# How can i redirect to certain section of the page using html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to redirect the links to a certain section of the page and i know by using id i can do that like this but i wanted http://localhost:5000/on/faq and http://localhost:5000/on/pricing
instead of http://localhost:5000/on#faq or http://localhost:5000/on#pricing so can anyone suggest me how can i do this

normal example

```
<a href ="#faq">faq</a>

<section id ="faq">
<h1>faq section</h1>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for as your question is a little confusing but, it sounds like instead of redirecting to a part of a specific page on screen you are wanting to redirect to another section of your website?

If this is the case then instead of using #faq you can use / instead of the # sign (as in /faq) as long as your faq is a completely separate file/page within your code.

Comment: no faq is a section not a seprate page and i want to use in /on/faq

Answer (score 0):

```
<section>
<h1>faq section</h1>
<a href="http://localhost:5000/on/faq">faq</a><br>
<a href="http://localhost:5000/on/pricing">pricing</a>
<section id="faq">
</section>
```

Will this work for you?